# JUnit JavaBean assert not null deep

Tags: junit, javabeans, assert, mybatis

How can a **JavaBean** be tested for **deep not null**?

I have a JavaBean with about **400 properties**. **MyBatis** fetches the data from a database and uses a **Result Map** to initialize the JavaBean. What I'm looking to do is test the Result Map for correctness. The first step I'm considering is to test for deep not null.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.beans.Introspector to get BeanInfo and getPropertyDescriptors().

Comment: it looks like `Introspector` only gets the property names. Consider an instance of an initialized JavaBean. Would an `Introspector` let me query it? The `getBeanInfo()` methods only take in objects of type `Class` as arguments.